# I want to resolve this error "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

Tags: oracle10g

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(EMP_ID NUMBER(5), F_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, L_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
EMAIL VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, PHONE_NO NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
JOB_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, SALARY NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, COMMISSION_PCT NUMBER(5), 
MANAGER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, DEPT_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_ED FOREIGN KEY (DEPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPT (DEPT_ID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_EDM FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER_ID) REFERENCES DEPT (MANAGER_ID));
```

When I add this line it is throwing the error `ORA-02270`.
I have already created the table DEPT which includes `dept_id` as primary key and `manager_id` as not null. But when I use foreign key as `dept_id` there is no error but for `manager_id` it is throwing the error.

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

dept_id is a primary key in DEPT, so you can have a foreign key for it in EMP.

manager_id is just a not-null column in DEPT. As it is not part of the primary key in DEPT, you cannot have a foreign key for it in EMP.